# Sum distinct rows and perform case when on result

Tags: sql-server

I am trying perform a logic after performing a sum if of volume on the concatenation of col1 and col2
for. e.g col3 of row 1 = (0.2 + -0.1 = 0.1)
row 2 = (12) etc

Based on the summation values i need to populate col3 such that if < 0 then return 0 else the summation value.

BEFORE

[image: BEFORE]

AFTER

[image: AFTER]

Query being used

```
UPDATE table
SET col =  (
           CASE WHEN 
           (SELECT ABS(SUM(B.VOLUME)) FROM table B 
            WHERE CONCAT(B.col1,B.col2) = CONCAT(col1,col2)) < 1 THEN 0
            ELSE (SELECT SUM(B.VOLUME) FROM table B WHERE CONCAT(B.col1,B.col2) = CONCAT(col1,col2))
            END
            )
        FROM table B
```

I cannot see what I am doing wrong.

Comment: show us your desired output

Comment: @surface Tension the desired output is up there.  I need col3 populated per shown.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? If using 2012+, I believe this update statement can be simply achieved with a `SUM() OVER()` window function. For example, `UPDATE B SET Col3 = CASE WHEN Total > 1 THEN Total ELSE 0 END FROM (SELECT *, Total = SUM(Volume) OVER (PARTITION BY Col1, Col2) FROM mytable) AS B;`

Comment: @ZLK thanks for the solution.  I have not come across over() before, but it has done the trick.  Much appreciated.  Feel free to post the answer and I will accept as the answer.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Question was answered by @ZLK with the below:

If using 2012+, I believe this update statement can be simply achieved with a SUM() OVER() window function.

For example,

```
UPDATE B 
SET Col3 = CASE WHEN Total > 1 THEN Total 
           ELSE 0 
           END 
           FROM (SELECT *, Total = SUM(Volume) OVER (PARTITION BY Col1, Col2) 
           FROM mytable) AS B;
```